# How to change a particular string in a text file?

Tags: python, list, text

Alright, I am writing a program so that it change the name of cars.For example, it replaces BMW with the new name I entered, without changing any other details. The problem is always end up emptying my text, and I know that I am using the write mode. Can anyone tell me how to fix this code

here is the format of my text file
BMW,2011,Automatic,50000,

'''

```
old = input("Old Name: ")
new = input("New Name: ")
result = ""

with open('Cars.txt', 'r') as file:
    var = file.readlines()

for row in var:
    element = row.split(',')
    if old in element:
        element[0] = new
        row = ",".join(element)
        result += row

with open('Cars.txt', 'w') as file:
    Write = file.write(result)
```

'''

Comment: What do you think the `'a'` in `open('Cars.txt', 'a')` does?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use `open('Cars.txt', 'w')` to overwite Cars.txt. The 'a' stands for 'append', while the 'w' stands for 'write'. You are also currently always editing the index [0], while the part of the list where the string to replace resides could be anywhere! There is probably a better implementation for this, but these changes should work + illustrate my point.

```
old = input("Old Name: ")
new = input("New Name: ")
result = ""

with open('Cars.txt', 'r') as file:
    var = file.readlines()

for row in var:
    element = row.split(',')
    if old in element:
        element[element.index(old)] = new
        row = ",".join(element)
        result += row

with open('Cars.txt', 'w') as file:
    Write = file.write(result)
```

Comment: I did, but it overwrites the whole file.

Comment: What are you trying to do, then? Your question implies that overwriting is what you are trying to do? If you're looking to edit just a part, you might want to just write the whole content back into the file with that part edited.

Comment: I have a text file as the one I just mentioned above. I want to change the name of the vehicle without changing anything else in my file.

Comment: @HamidrezaMaleki Ok, I updated this answer based on that information.

Comment: @HamidrezaMaleki Did this answer your question, or is there more information?